# Geometry Nodes : set position based on distorted UVs

Tags: uv, geometry-nodes

I've been fighting with this for hours and can't wrap my head around it.

I am using geo nodes to distort the U axis of some UVs using a float curve. I then use the distorted UVs to display an image. The result looks like this :

[image: distort UVs]

My goal is to be able to move points along a line so it follows the UV distortion. But if I use the distorted UVs as is to set the points position, this moves the points in the opposite direction.

[image: move points using distorted UVs]

And this is normal, this is how UVs work : lower U value means "image going to the right", as for position, lower values means "points moving to the left".

So as I understand it, I need to reproduce how UV sampling works :

- first sample the distorted U axis
- then find the correct position along the curve from the sampled value

Ex : if the distortion gives me a value of 0.05, I need to find **where along the U axis is there a value of 0.05**, and extract a position from that.

The problem is, I have no clue how to do so. I tried using the "Sample Curve" node, but to no avail.

Here's what my node tree looks like for now :

[image]

And here's the blend file :

[image]

Any help is welcome. Thanks for reading !

edit : added blend file

Comment: Why not simply move the vertices of the grid, instead of updating the UV? It would have the same visual effect, and you would move the points of the indicator below in the same exact way as you moved vertices…

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Thanks for your answer. I would if I could, but this is only part of a more complex project, which demands the UVs to be distorted :/ I like your idea though, I'll see if I can somehow change the process.